# Re renderling AppBar component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-redux-form

I have an `AppBar` Component as shown below

```
<AppBar title="Shopping List App" showMenuIconButton={true}
                    iconElementRight={checkAuthenticationToken()?<Menu/>:null}
                    iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
                />
```

the `iconElementRight` should only render the `Menu` Component after the `checkAuthenticationToken()` evaluates to true which it does after login. However, it is not and I have to manually refresh the browser for it to show up. I believe it is because nothing is changing for the `AppBar` component and therefore its `render` method is not called again. My question Is how Can I refresh the `AppBar` or all `ReactDom` on successful login?

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(muiTheme)}>
                <AppBar title="Shopping List App" showMenuIconButton={true}
                    iconElementRight={checkAuthenticationToken()?<Menu/>:null}
                    iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
                />
                <div className="container">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" render={requireLogin}/>
                        <Route path="/login" render={isLoggedIn}/>
                        <Route path="/register" component={RegisterForm}/>
                        <Route path="/shoppinglists" render={requireLogin}/>
                        <Route path="/:id/shoppinglist_items" render={itemsRequireLogin}/>
                        <Route component={NotFound}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I am using redux to maintain state @Ma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your component is't connected to redux store, state changes won't trigger a new render, so you won't have your component updated.

The way it is right now, it'll only perform this check when the `render` method get's called...

One possible solution is wrap your `AppBar`component into another one that is connected to redux state, so it'll update whenever the part of the state you need is updated in the store

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) {
  const { isAuthenticated } = state.authentication // Get whatever you need from the reducer that handles authentication state
  return { isAuthenticated } 
}

class MyAppBar extends Component {
  ...

  render(){
    return(<AppBar iconElementRight={this.props.isAuthenticated ? <Menu /> : null} {rest of your props})
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyAppBar)
```

This way, any changes on the store related to the authentication reducer will be tracked by the component and will trigger the render method (Performing the check when it's needed)